# Need to scroll UITableView to update UILabel frame inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel, frame

I want to update a `UILabel` frame(just origin.y position) inside `UITableViewCell` depending on a certain condition, thus, I'm using that code to achieve that:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(EventsCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if([[arrayofImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]isEqualToString:@"no image"]){
        [cell.imageImageView removeFromSuperview];
        cell.imageImageView=nil;
        cell.yearLabel.frame=CGRectMake(cell.yearLabel.frame.origin.x,42, cell.yearLabel.frame.size.width, cell.yearLabel.frame.size.height );
    }
}
```

The problem is that I need to scroll the `UITableView` cell to get the `UILabel`'s frame updated(setting the y position to 42).
Why I have such problem even that this code is executed even before the creation of the cell(in the `willDisplayCell` delegate method).
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely due to auto layout. If instead of changing the frame, you make an IBOutlet to the constraint between the label and the top of the cell, and modify its constant value, it should work properly (topCon is my outlet to the constraint).

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(EventsCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if([[arrayofImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]isEqualToString:@"no image"]){
        [cell.imageImageView removeFromSuperview];
        cell.imageImageView=nil;
        cell.topCon.constant = 42;
    }
}
```